# debug C code for calculating deposit am a beginner

Tags: c

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int year;
    double capital, rate;
    float deposit;
    char a, y, n;
    printf("Input rate, year, capital:");
    printf("Compound interest (Y/N)?");
    scanf("%lf,%d,%lf", &capital, &year, &rate);
    scanf(" %c", &a);
    if (a = 'y')
    {
        deposit = capital*pow((1 + rate), n);
        printf("deposit = %.4f\n");
    }
    else if (a = 'n')
    {
        deposit = capital*(1 + rate * n);
        printf("deposit = %.4f\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know how to deal with this:

[image: snap shot]

I want to calculate deposit with known capital, year and year.
If I input y, I will use deposit  =  capital * (1 + rate) n
if i input n, I will use deposit  =  capital  * (1 + rate * n)

Comment: if (a='y') <--- Change this to if (a=='y'). Use double equals to check for equality. Same with (a='n')

Comment: `printf("deposit = %.4f\n");` --> `printf("deposit = %.4f\n", deposit  );`

Comment: Aside: why is `float deposit;` and not `double deposit;`?

Comment: The `n` you are using in calculations (for some reason `char n`) is an *uninitialised variable* which will give *undefined behaviour*. Did you mean to use `year`, whose value you enter but do not use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code does not even compile without warnings or errors.

Comment: You should work together with class mates and ask for help from your teacher or your seniors where you study. Or if you are alone start learning how to search on internet before you start to code.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple issues.

```
if(a = 'y')
.
.
.
if(a = 'n')
```

These are valid statements, but not what you are actually wanting to do.
When your if statement has an asignment operator in it, you're only checking to see if the assignment is a success. So in your case if you assign 'y' to a.

You want to check to see if a already contains 'y'
it should be

```
if(a == 'y')
.
.
.
if(a == 'n')
```

Next, you're always getting 0 because you forgot to print out deposit.

```
printf("deposit = %.4f\n");
```

should be

```
printf("deposit = %.4f\n", deposit);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main error here is with your if-statement condition:

> a = 'y'

Use one equal sign only when declaring and assigning values. You need two equal signs when comparing values.

It should be:

> a == 'y'

Same for the else-if condition.